# How to convert chinese name into korean name?

Tags: hangul, hanja, names

I've done a lot of research due converting my chinese name to hangul, but I can't find out how, since my characters rarely used. How do I translate my chinese name: 汪凌飞 (Wang Ling Fei) to hangul characters?

Comment: an edit was made on your question recently. In case there are any errors in the edit or it not something you intended to write, please roll back the edit or let me know here in the comment.

Comment: @user17915 I think you're right and it's helpful that a moderator's stepped in to address this issue. I think the edit by "dROOOze" converted 날 비 from simplified to traditional (I may be wrong, I don't know Chinese) and I'm unsure whether this was necessary nor helpful

Comment: @winter You can also edit your question back to its original form

Comment: This is a request for help in a Korean forum, and 飞 is not a valid character in Korean. It’s generally inappropriate to use Simplified Chinese in a non-Chinese site and expect the users of the site to know what you’re talking about.

Comment: @dROOOze I speak native Korean, I know 한문. 날 비 is one of the most basic 한자 characters as any native Korean speaker would know. Online 한자 dictionaries are perfectly capable of matching most simplified characters with traditional forms, thus rendering your previous edit materially insignificant and if anything a source for more confusion, which is why I assume the moderator stepped in to ensure that the questioner was okay with this. I certainly was confused and didn't feel the edit was relevant to adding clarification to an already pretty basic question.

Comment: @user13229973 Can you show me a Korean language dictionary or official resource with a list of Hanja (as used in the Korean language) which includes Simplified Chinese characters (as used in China)? I went on Naver's Hanja dictionary and very surprisingly, they include all Simplified Chinese characters (even ones exclusively invented by the Chinese Communist Party after 1956, [such as 卫](https://hanja.dict.naver.com/#/search?query=%E5%8D%AB&range=all)). Are you suggesting that these characters are used in Korean?

Comment: @dROOOze Would you kindly re-read my comment? I said verbatim online 한자 dictionaries are perfectly capable of matching simplified with traditional characters. I have no idea what you're on about with the Communist Party of China, which once again I think is entirely irrelevant to anything related to the study of Korean and in particular to this question, and I think that's the end of this discussion. Thanks.

Comment: I approved @user13229973's proposed edit. I also think the original characters should stay. That's literally how the questioner writes their own name, and you can't tell someone they're writing their own name wrong in their own language. (And nobody suggested that 飞 is a valid character in Korean writing, so I don't think that point is relevant.)

Comment: @jick uhh, yes, the proposed “answer” and that author literally gives a Korean dictionary style eumhun entry for 飞, implying that the character is used in Korean, which is incredibly confusing and I believe wrong.

Comment: To both @jick and "dROOOze" (I can't tag you here for some reason): I realize in hindsight that I was beyond excessive and abrasive in tone and attitude. It's ironic because I'm critical of others yet in hindsight I was an infinite times worse. Native doesn't mean expert, I'm far from it. Although not an excuse, I also didn't interpret your question properly, dROOOze. Once again I'm sorry for my previous comments, and I'll take this opportunity to behave more appropriately here on this forum.

Comment: @dROOOze, please read my comment above.

Comment: i believe your name converted would be 왕릉비

Answer (score 1):

It is '왕릉비' in Korean characters.

Please see below links for each character.

왕: https://hanja.dict.naver.com/#/entry/ccko/7b1d2201254f4f0090a493a66643ccca

릉: https://hanja.dict.naver.com/#/entry/ccko/c8650d3e39ea47f1b14ee829c3ae5a7b

비: https://hanja.dict.naver.com/#/entry/ccko/1608ab2bdc384b04bd41de1ad172db25

Answer (score 0):

Both "왕릉비" and "왕링페이" are acceptable. The former is obtained by picking Korean name for each hanja in your name, while the latter is a transliteration of your Chinese name. "왕릉비" is less formal than "왕링페이" but both are suitable for you to declare as your Korean name; which is better is really just a matter of taste.